# Generate random sequence in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to generate random numbers into 2 columns where the first column is from_number and second column in to_number.

My query looks as following

```
select to_char(5001 + (level-1)),
       to_char(5005 + (level-1))          
  from dual 
connect by level <= 100;
```

My output is for the above query is:

```
5001    5005
5002    5006
5003    5007
5004    5008
5005    5009
```

and so on...

But my output should be like following:

```
5001    5005
5006    5010
5011    5015
5016    5020
```

and so on...

The second-row 'from_number' should be the first-row 'to_number'+1

How can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that what you are using here is not a random sequence. It is a fixed sequence. To know how to generate random number read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/network.804/a54082/ch5rndm.htm)

Now coming back to your question, you can do it by playing a little with `level`. Note I reduced the `<=100` to `<=20` as we are using a multiplier of `5` so the maximum value you will get is `5005 + 20*5 - 5` = `6000`. Change it back to `<=100` if you want total of `100` rows.

```
select 
 to_char(5001 + (level*5) - 5 ),
 to_char(5005 + (level*5) - 5)          
from dual 
connect by level <= 20;
```

Comment: Thanks, Utsav.This worked.But when I changed it for my requirement where it is 16 digits number, it is not giving desired results.The second row 'from_number' is showing as the first row 'to_number'.I tried using '5321050000000000' as my 16 digit number. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: select 
 to_char(5321050000000000  + (level*5) - 5 ),
 to_char(5321050000000005  + (level*5) - 5)
from dual 
connect by level <= 21;

Comment: I am guessing that `first` and `second` rows are only for your client. Use an`order by` on the first column so your client will show you data in an order.

Comment: Use `order by 1` at the end and check again

Comment: select 
 to_char(5321050000000000  + (level*5) - 5 ),
 to_char(5321050000000005  + (level*5) - 5)
from dual 
connect by level <= 21 order by 1;

Comment: That's is because you started with 5321....00, u should start with 5321....01. Check this.  `select to_char(5321050000000001 + (level*5) - 5 ), to_char(5321050000000005 + (level*5) - 5) from dual connect by level <= 21 order by 1`